# Spring Cloud Data Flow Runtime instance does not show stdout and stderr

Tags: stdout, stderr, spring-cloud-dataflow

I can't figured out why I don't see in Spring Cloud Data Flow in **Runtime** instances two extra properties **stdout** and **stderr**? I would like to get path to logs.
Made a lot of research on the internet with no luck.

[image]

Is there any property needed on deployment of stream? or any setup on SCDF?

Data Flow Server Implementation:
Name: spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local
Version: 1.7.0.M1

Browser Google Chrome: Version 73.0.3683.103 (64-bit)

java -XX:MaxRAM=512m -Dspring.config.location=/skipper.yaml -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /spring-cloud-skipper-server.jar

Tried on Firefox: 66.0.2 (64-bit)

And as requested I checked Console logs, do find any errors in browsers.

[image]

Comment: Wow! That is very odd! Could you help us by updating the description with versions in use and the browser+version?

Comment: As for the logs, alternatively, you can find the application log-path printed in Skipper's logs, too. You can simply then tail the copied path directly.

Comment: details provided

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating the post with more details!

It seems that you're on 1.7 M1 - I was able to verify the fields exist on this release, though. I'm also on Chrome: `Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)` -

[image]

As next steps, perhaps you could check to see if there are any browser console errors. If you do see something, please share it. Maybe also try it on a different browser to confirm the behavior.

Aside: Why are you using a milestone release in the first place? Please switch to a GA release even if you're only experimenting and not targeting to go production yet. The latest on 1.7.x line is [v1.7.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-deploying-spring-cloud-dataflow) and I verified the stdout/stderr components.

In fact, I'd recommend that you switch to the latest GA release on 2.0.x line. It is at [v2.0.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-local-deploying-spring-cloud-dataflow-docker) right now. You should see the stdout/stderr components here as well.

Comment: Tested on Firefox, checked console logs, please find updated info above

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried a GA version? What happens on one of the GA releases? (I highly recommend switching from 1.7 M1 regardless)

Comment: I can't switch to GA, I work in a big company, it is not me, who make this type of decisions.